# error: conversion from 'const char [5]' to non-scalar type in c++

Tags: c++, string

```
public:
    string str;

    Test(string& str){
        this->str=str;
        cout<<"constructor"<<endl;
    }
 

};

int main() {
    Test t="test";
    return 0;
}
```

In this code I get the error `"..\src\Test.cpp:30:9: error: conversion from 'const char [5]' to non-scalar type 'Test' requested "`?

Why is then the following code ok?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test{

public:
    string str;

    Test(string str){
        this->str=str;
        cout<<"constructor"<<endl;
    }

    Test(const Test &test){
        cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
        this->str=test.str;
    }

};

int main() {
    Test t=Test("test");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Petesh This is construction, not assignment.

Comment: because string has an default constructor for const char*.

Comment: misread the code, deleted inaccurate comment. feel a bit like a muppet for making the comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Test t="test";
```

This tries to:

- Convert the string literal (which is an array of characters, `char[5]`) into a temporary `string`
- Convert the temporary `string` to `Test`

This fails for two reasons:

- An implicit conversion sequence can't involve more than one user-defined conversion. Two are needed here.
- A temporary can't bind to a non-const *lvalue* reference, which is what your conversion constructor `Test(string&)` wants.

Your second example fixes these problems by:

- Making the conversion from `string` to `Test` explicit, `Test(...)`. Now there is only one implicit conversion, from `char[5]` to `string`. Note that this is rather a verbose way to initialise it; `Test t("test")` would do the same thing.
- Declaring the conversion constructor to take `string` by value, not reference. A const reference, `const string&`, would also work, as would a `const char*`.

Both of these changes are necessary, since each fixes just one of the two problems.

Comment: this always troubled me , now assigning a string literal, why will the compiler create a temp string object? is it language defined thing to be as such? and during creation of object if the obect has overloaded `=` why it triggers copy assignment constructor instead of the overloaded operator?

Comment: @Koushik: Because the only suitable constructor for `Test` (once it's fixed to take a value or `const` reference) requires a string object. If there were a constructor taking `const char*`, then the literal could be passed directly to that without creating a temporary.

Comment: In your comments to another answer you say const reference to string would not work, as I state in my answer. [GCC agrees](http://ideone.com/7YYR08) unless I missed something. So, which one is it?

Comment: @juanchopanza: *Just* changing the constructor to take a const reference won't work, because there are two problems. You need a constructor taking a value or const reference *and* an explicit conversion to make the conversion sequence valid - as my answer says.

Comment: Oh I see, I missed the **and**.

Comment: @MikeSeymour even if the constructor has `const string&` it should work right? and why in `Test t="test";` the constructor is invoked if `= is overloaded?` doesnt the above statement convert to something like `Test t; t = "literal"`?

Comment: @Koushik: As for your second question, initialisation is not assignment even if it involves the `=` token, so initialisation is done using a constructor, not an assignment operator.

Comment: @Koushik: `Test t="test"` won't work because it requires two user-defined conversions, `char[5]` to `string`, and `string` to `Test`. Only one is allowed in an implicit conversion sequence - as my answer says.

Comment: ah thanks. yes the first part of the question is clear from your answer. thanks again.

Comment: I wonder why the `const char*` variant works then (see [demo](http://ideone.com/jsRifp)). In principle it involves the same number of conversions, yet g++ allows it. I based my answer on that but now I am not so sure it is correct.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It only requires one user-defined conversion, `const char*` to `Test`. The array-to-pointer conversion is a standard conversion, and an implicit conversion can contain as many standard conversions as it needs.

Comment: Of course, thanks. I would say I haven't had enough coffee yet but I don't even have that excuse.

Comment: @MikeSeymour **Test t = std::string("test");** why it's not calling copy constructor. std::string("test") will create a temp test obj and copy initialize **t** using that temp obj, so copy constructor should be called at this time. What I'm missing here.?

Answer (score 2):

You are only allowed one implicit conversion between user defined types. Your code has an implicit conversion from `const char[6]` (which decays to `const char*`) to `std::string`, and from `std::string` to `Test`. This is the reason changing the signature to `Test(const std::string&)` [will not work](http://ideone.com/7YYR08).

Try changing the constructor signature to

```
#include <string>

struct Test
{
  Test(const char* c) : s_(c) {}
  std::string s_;
};

int main()
{
  Test t = "Hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `const` to accept `"test"` which is a constant literal :

```
Test(const string& str) : str(str) {
     ^^^^^
}
```

and use it like

```
Test t("test");

or

Test t = string("test");
```

*[Live code](http://ideone.com/tchNul)*

Comment: @MikeSeymour it will on MSVC, yes this is flaw of MS compiler, but I think he tried. At least I did, compiled without single warning.

Answer (score 0):

Test t="test";
The complier will try to find a construtor: Test(const char*),
but you just define a Test(string&), so it popup the error.

your can try to define a constructor such as Test(const char*) or modify your code like this: Test t = string("test")