# C++17 class template argument deduction guides and string literals

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

The constructor takes `T` by value, so string literals will decay to `char const*`.

With the deduction guide `Stack(char const*) -> Stack<std::string>`,
I expect both cases to work.

Why the second argument deduction `Stack ss2 = "string literal"` does not?

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>

template<typename T>
class Stack {
    std::vector<T> elems;
public:
    Stack() = default;
    Stack(T elm) : elems({std::move(elm)}) { }
};

Stack(char const*) -> Stack<std::string>;

void test() {
    Stack ss1 { "works fine."};
    // error: conversion from 'const char [15]' to
    // non-scalar type 'Stack<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' 
    // requested
    Stack ss2 = "compile error!"; 
}
```

Compiler explorer : https://godbolt.org/g/z3PaBp

Answer (score 0):

`Stack ss2 = "compile error!";`

This tries to:

- Convert the string literal (which is an array of characters, char[15]) into a temporary string
- Convert the temporary string to Stack

This fails for this reason:

- An implicit conversion sequence can't involve more than one user-defined conversion. Two are need

See the complete answer to a duplicate question here [error: conversion from 'const char [5]' to non-scalar type in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252455)